# typescript, Argument of type 'xxx' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

Tags: typescript

`typescript` give me this hint when I write a `new Error({code: 404, msg: 'user is not existed'})` statement.

`[ts] Argument of type '{ code: number; msg: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.`

How can I solve this? Here is my code snippet:

```
const fetchData_V2 = (num: number): Promise<User> => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if(num > 0) {
        const user: User = new User('novaline', 26);
        resolve(user);
      } else {
        reject(new Error({code: 404, msg: 'user not exist'}));
      }

    }, 1000);
  });
}
```

Comment: Because the `Error` constructor requires a string as its first parameter. Check out the type definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the definition for the `Error` constructor:

```
interface ErrorConstructor {
    new (message?: string): Error;
    (message?: string): Error;
    readonly prototype: Error;
}
```

Check out the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error):

> `new Error([message[, fileName[, lineNumber]]])`
>           `message` Optional. Human-readable description of the error.